# Configure max.poll.interval.ms for a specified topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

As I can see in this document https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_max.poll.interval.ms there is a parameter in kafka which controls the maximum time between poll invocations before the consumer will proactively leave the group.

Is there anyway to configure this parameter to apply to only a specific topic ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a consumer level config which means you would need a brand new consumer instance with a different config and subscribe to only that topic (assuming you want more time to process a set of messages from a specific topic but not the rest you subscribe to).